# My jQuery scroll to span class isn't working, what am I missing?

Tags: jquery, class, scroll, html

I took a example and plugin for scroll to certain element on page. When you click previous an next you can navigate with scroll from one span to another with the same class... Source demo is working in a little different way. I tried to modify it a little bit and now I don't know why is not working? where am I wrong?

Source demo: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/scrollto-demo/

My Situation till now: http://jsfiddle.net/64UBs/1/

html:

```
<div id="nav-dock"> 
  <a id="prev" href="#">&uarr; Prev</a> 
  <a id="next" href="#">&darr; Next</a>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class=text>
  <b>First</b>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In iaculis augue sapien, in  facilisis lorem ullamcorper eu. 
  Nunc at nulla metus. Pellentesque posuere quam id nunc <span class="highlight1">posuere</span> sagittis. 
  Vivamus varius euismod nisi, ac condimentum mauris aliquam vitae. Ut faucibus eros vitae pharetra eleifend. P
  ellentesque volutpat facilisis porttitor. Nullam in turpis a nulla placerat placerat.    
</div>
<br<br><br><br><br><br>
<div class=text>
  <b>Second</b>
  Cras semper purus sit amet euismod molestie. Vivamus dapibus hendrerit elit eget tristique. 
  Ut pulvinar adipiscing magna, eget viverra risus sollicitudin et. Morbi odio lacus, malesuada vel dapibus vitae, blandit ut metus. 
  Vivamus cursus fringilla <span class="highlight1">felis</span> id facilisis.   
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class=text>
  <b>Third</b>
  Aliquam et mattis mi. Mauris vel sagittis orci, id tempor neque. Aenean at arcu eu quam suscipit fermentum. 
  Sed tempor, urna in malesuada sollicitudin, nulla erat <span class="highlight1">malesuada</span> ligula, sed ultricies ipsum dui a dui. 
  Ut at sem quis lectus aliquet vulputate.     
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class=text>
  <b>Fifth</b>
  Praesent sagittis tortor a purus euismod ultrices eu vitae est. Vivamus a facilisis dolor. 
  Donec id tincidunt erat. Fusce elementum imperdiet augue, at pretium lectus <span class="highlight1">dictum</span> sit amet. 
  Nullam pharetra dui arcu, ut tempus nulla interdum non. Etiam et mattis augue.    
</div>
```

script:

```
$(function() {

function scroll(direction) {

    var scroll, i,
            positions = [],
            here = $(window).scrollTop(),
            collection = $('.highlight1');

    collection.each(function() {
        positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset()['top'],10));
    });

    for(i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        if (direction == 'next' && positions[i] > here) { scroll = collection.get(i);  break; }
        if (direction == 'prev' && i > 0 && positions[i] >= here) { scroll = collection.get(i-1); break; }
    }

    if (scroll) {
        $.scrollTo(scroll, {
            duration: 750       
        });
    }

    return false;
}

$("#next,#prev").click(function() {        
    return scroll($(this).attr('id'));        
});

});
```

css:

```
#nav-dock {
    position: fixed;
    right: 15px;
    top: 35%;
}
#nav-dock a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    margin: 3px 0;
    background: #666;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
#nav-dock a:hover {
    background: #000;
}
#nav-dock #next {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Must say all those `<br>`s are hurting my eyes. This is easier done with `margin` or `padding` properties

Comment: yea in real project, it's solved like that.... `br`s are here just for quick example in jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to be the version of jquery you are using.  I updated you jsfiddle to 1.7.2 and it seems ok.

HTH

Comment: thanks... it works now... it would be great if it would work on lastest jquery

Comment: I tried 1.9 and even with the migration file in place, no good.  1.7 seems to be the latest.